# This element <ion-select-option#ion-selopt-0.md.hydrated> is not visible because it has CSS property: display: none

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, cypress

I'm writing a Cypress test to select options from ion-select-option.  Typically I'd use Cypress select() command with the ('option text') but that doesn't work. So as a work around I'm using the following:

```js
    cy.get('[data-cy="gender-dropdown"]').eq(0).contains('Woman').click();
```

This gets me a little closer, it opens the drop down option 'Woman' but it won't select the option because of the following error:

This element <ion-select-option#ion-selopt-0.md.hydrated> is not visible because it has CSS property: display: none

Even when I add the css property to display: anything but none, then it gives me another error related to pixels = 0.

Here's the actual HTML:

```html
      <ion-select formControlName="gender" placeholder="*Gender">
        <ion-select-option data-cy="gender-dropdown" *ngFor="let genOption of genderOptions"> {{genOption}}</ion-select-option>
      </ion-select>
```

[image: INSPECTED ELEMENT]

I know once I'm able to select the option, I will probably have issues clicking the 'Done' button on the drop down.

I've googled this issue as well as searched Stack to no avail.
I've also tried using {force: true} in the click() method but that doesn't actually click the option.  The test simply passes without it ever clicking the option.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ionic-framework & angular but I recommend you to set `data-cy` in `ion-select` and then click on it to open the drop-down menu. Wait until the drop-down open then click the `select-option`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice in the screenshot the testing attribute `data-cy="gender-dropdown"` does not appear.

If you search upwards (inside `<ion-router-outlet>`) the element that has the data-cy attribute is

```html
<ion-select-option _ngcontent-dwb-c144="" data-cy="gender-dropdown" value="Woman" 
  ...
  class="md hydrated">Woman</ion-select-option>
```

but it's not the one you want to click.

Assuming you have opened the select a popup appears, a new section is added dynamically to the DOM with values based on the `data-cy="gender-dropdown"` tagged elements.

Unfortunately the popup does not carry the data-cy attribute, but you can search for the text within the `ion-alert` element:

```js
// Opening the select
cy.contains('label', '*Gender')  // placeholder label
  .parent()                      // parent ion-select
  .click()                       // open

// Choosing the option
cy.get('ion-alert').within(() => {                       // popup section
  cy.contains('button.select-interface-option', 'Woman').click()
})
```